# SQL keep the 500 most recent items for 44 foreign keys in one table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following 3 columns

```
Recid (primary key), different_recid(foreign key), and details
```

I want to write a query for a 10 specific `different_recids` to delete all rows for those `different_recids` only except the most recent.

Anyone have suggestions.

Comment: You need an extra term on the JOIN in line#3.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    RecID           INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Different_RecID INT,
    Create_Date     DATETIME
);

INSERT  @MyTable (Different_Recid, Create_Date)
SELECT  1, '20130101' UNION ALL 
SELECT  1, '20130102' UNION ALL 
SELECT  1, '20130103' UNION ALL 

SELECT  2, '20130211' UNION ALL 
SELECT  2, '20130212' UNION ALL 

SELECT  3, '20130102' UNION ALL 
SELECT  3, '20130103';

DECLARE @RowsToDelete TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT  @RowsToDelete VALUES (1);
INSERT  @RowsToDelete VALUES (2);

DELETE  [Target]
-- OUTPUT   deleted.* -- <-- Uncomment this line to see deleted rows
FROM
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Different_RecID ORDER BY x.Create_Date DESC) RowNum, x.*
        FROM    @MyTable x
        WHERE   EXISTS 
        (   
            SELECT  *
            FROM    @RowsToDelete d 
            WHERE   x.Different_RecID = d.ID
        )
    ) src
    WHERE src.RowNum > 1
) AS [Target];
```

Results:

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTable;
/*
RecID Different_RecID Create_Date
----- --------------- -----------
3     1               2013-01-03
5     2               2013-02-12
6     3               2013-01-02
7     3               2013-01-03
*/
```